# How do I query all invoices created since a date in Stripe with PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm trying to query all invoices that have been created since a certain date using the PHP library with Stripe and the UI is showing me 200, but when I query, it's only returning 20. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, is there any guidance on how to handle this?

```
$search = array("limit" => 1000);
$search["date"] = array('gte'=>strtotime("02/01/2018"));
$invoices = \Stripe\Invoice::all($search);
```

My submission:

```
Array
(
    [limit] => 1000
    [date] => Array
        (
            [gte] => 1517443200
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only set a limit up to 100 there, so you'll likely want to use [auto-pagination](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#auto-pagination) in this case to get all of them.

It might also be that your date is being ambiguously parsed - is it Feb 1, or Jan 2? - so you may want to switch that to a less ambiguous string format like `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: The date format is working fine, and reducing to 100 doesn't help. For some reason it keeps only returning 20.

Comment: The only way it would return 20 is if there are only 20 for the criteria you've specified, so I'd try changing the date format.

Comment: Just for clarity sake, I realized I was querying in our dev environment instead of production so it was returning the incorrect invoices.

Comment: Well, that's ... definitely another viable explanation. :)